My secondary SharePoint database server wont restart
The server needs to be restarted. It shows me a message about it on server manager dashboard. But when I Try to restart nothing happens. Why is this so?

What message? What did you try?

@jleture, the message is "t the SharePoint server needs to be restarted". I tried restarting it using the Windows restart button.

Can you click the button or ask an administrator to do it.
